# ormlite select count(*) as typeCount group by type

Tags: ormlite

I want to do something like this in OrmLite

```
SELECT *, COUNT(title) as titleCount from table1 group by title;
```

Is there any way to do this via QueryBuilder without the need for queryRaw?

Comment: I think this is a good question as examples seem lacking that clarify this issue.  It seems like most people figure out something that works and move on.  The ORMLite documentation itself basically says 'This API method exists, for more information here is a SQL reference', which does not substitute for an example of valid uses of ORMLite!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that the use of COUNT() and the like necessitates the use of `selectRaw()`.  I hoped for a way around this - not having to write my SQL as strings is the main reason I chose to use ORMLite.

http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder

> selectRaw(String... columns):
>   Add raw columns or aggregate functions
>   (COUNT, MAX, ...) to the query. This will turn the query into
>   something only suitable for using as a raw query. This can be called
>   multiple times to add more columns to select. See section Issuing Raw
>   Queries.

Further information on the use of `selectRaw()` as I was attempting much the same thing:

Documentation states that if you use `selectRaw()` it will "turn the query into" one that is supposed to be called by `queryRaw()`.

What it does not explain is that normally while multiple calls to `selectColumns()` or `selectRaw()` are valid (if you exclusively use one or the other), 
use of `selectRaw()` after `selectColumns()` has a 'hidden' side-effect of wiping out any `selectColumns()` you called previously.

I believe that the ORMLite documentation for `selectRaw()` would be improved by a note that its use is not intended to be mixed with `selectColumns()`.

```
QueryBuilder<EmailMessage, String> qb = emailDao.queryBuilder();
qb.selectColumns("emailAddress"); // This column is not selected due to later use of selectRaw()!
qb.selectRaw("COUNT (emailAddress)");
```

ORMLite examples are not as plentiful as I'd like, so here is a complete example of something that works:

```
QueryBuilder<EmailMessage, String> qb = emailDao.queryBuilder();        
qb.selectRaw("emailAddress"); // This can also be done with a single call to selectRaw()
qb.selectRaw("COUNT (emailAddress)");
qb.groupBy("emailAddress");
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = qb.queryRaw(); // Returns results with two columns
```

Comment: Lot of complaining about ORMLite here but as far as I can tell, you've not submitted any issues in Github or tried to contact the developer.  As of version 5.0, `selectRaw(...)` and `selectColumns(...)` can coexist.  See this test: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/b02c229ad521a175c5a969cf401efa28f36cea1e

Comment: Any other improvements that you can recommend for ORMLite to better handle raw queries?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this via `QueryBuilder` without the need for `queryRaw(...)`?

The short answer is no because ORMLite wouldn't know what to do with the extra count value.  If you had a `Table1` entity with a DAO definition, what field would the `COUNT(title)` go into?  Raw queries give you the power to select various fields but then you need to process the results.

With the code right now (v5.1), you can define a [custom `RawRowMapper`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/RawRowMapper.html) and then use the [`dao.getRawRowMapper()` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#getRawRowMapper--) to process the results for `Table1` and tack on the `titleCount` field by hand.

I've got an idea how to accomplish this in a better way in ORMLite.  I'll look into it.