# What's the correct and optimized way to "Group By" and "Max" or "most recent" values with ORMLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

What's the correct and most optimized way to "Group By" and "Max" or "most recent" values of field? (with ORMLite preferably)

I want to "group by" results but getting the most recent value from a field of date type.

something like:

```
-- records:

1, hello, 1985
2, hello, 1991
3, hello, 1990
4, hello world, 2015
5, hello world, 2010
6, hello world, 2000
```

i should get after running the query/ormlite functions something like this:

```
-- grouping by string field (column 2) 
-- and the most recent value of year (column 3)
-- so results should be like this:

2, hello, 1991
4, hello world, 2015
```

Comment: Documentation is light in this area, but if you are aggregating using ORMLite you will probably need to use queryRaw(), see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084859/ormlite-select-count-as-typecount-group-by-type/48492536#48492536